# Understand the statement of the ratio test

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to understand the  statement of the ratio test

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#:~:text=satisfy%20this%20case.-,It%20is%20possible,-to%20make%20the](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#:%7E:text=satisfy%20this%20case.-,It%20is%20possible,-to%20make%20the)

Can anyone explain "It is possible to make the ratio test applicable to certain cases where the limit $ L$ fails to exist, if limit superior and limit inferior are used" statement with examples?

Is it possible $L$ fails to exist and series is convergent?

Comment: Try the ratio test with the convergent series $\;\sum\frac1{n^2}\;$ . It fails...

Comment: @DonAntonio  Thank you but I want to know $L$ is fails to exist but  limit superior and limit inferior are used to this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{n: a_n=0\}$ is finite and if

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup \{|a_{m+1}|/|a_m|:m\ge n\}<1$

then $\sum_na_n$ converges.

Proof: Suppose $1>r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup \{|a_{m+1}|/|a_m|:m\ge n\}$.

Let $s=(1+r)/2.$ Then $1>s>r$. And there are only finitely many $n$ for which $[\,a_n=0\lor |a_{n+1}|>s|a_n|\,].$

So take $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\ge n_0\implies[\, a_n\ne 0\land |a_{n+1}|\le s|a_n| \,].$ By induction, $$\forall n\ge n_0\,(\,|a_n|\le s^{n-n_0}|a_{n_0}|\,).$$  Since $0<s<1$, the Cauchy Criterion is now easily shown to be satisfied for $\sum_na_n.$

Example: Let $a_1=0$ and $a_2=1.$ For $n\ge 2$ let $a_{n+1}/a_n=1/(3+(-1)^n).$ Then $\lim\sup |a_{n+1}/a_n|=1/2$ so $\sum_n a_n$ converges, but $\lim |a_{n+1}/a_n|$ does not exist.

Similarly if $\{n:a_n=0\}$ is finite and if $1<\lim\inf |a_{n+1}/a_n|$ then $\sum_na_n$ diverges.

Comment: your example is not quite understandable what do you mean $a_1=1$ and $a_1=0$

Comment: Typos fixed. Thank you for catching it.

Comment: Can you please tell me meaning of $\{n :a_n=0\}$ I  am not familer with this

Comment: $\{n:a_n=0\}$ is the set of all those and only those $n$ for which $a_n=0. $ In my example$ a_n=0\iff n=1$ so  $1$ is the only member of the set in this case. .....Saying  "$\{n:a_n=0\}$ is finite" means the number of non-$0$ terms in the sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,...)$ is not infinite.